# Get percentage per level

Tags: php, progress-bar, percentage

I've created a level system based on posts.

```
Level 1 = 1-25 posts
Level 2 = 26-50 posts
Level 3 = 51-250 posts, etc...
```

I also wanted to show a progress bar

Normally you would so something like this:

```
$author_posts = 15;
$progress = ($author_posts * 100) / 25; //(level 1)
```

The progress percentage is then `60%`.

But what should I use if user reached `level 3` already?

```
if( $author_posts >= '250' ) {
    $progress   = '100';
} elseif( $author_posts < '51' ) {
    $progress   = '0';
} else {
    $progress   = // what should I use here?
}


<div class="progress-bar" style="width:<?php echo esc_attr( $progress ); ?>%;"></div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by percentage? Is it percent until next level?

Comment: basic math = ($author_posts / 250) *100

Comment: It's percentage inside the current level (level3). Or as in how much percentage is done till level 3 is cleared. I think it should be something like this but I'm not sure: `$progress ( $author_posts * 100 ) / ( 250 - 51 );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your included `if` block implies that a user is at 0% progress until they hit the lower boundary for that level. Can we then assume that none of the previous posts beneath that boundary count as a percentage once it is breached? This means only posts 51 to 250 count as percentage points, giving a range of 200 posts (inclusive). So 1 post = 0.5%.

If so

```
$progress = round( ( ( $author_posts - 51 ) / 200 ) * 100 )
```

> 51 posts = 0%
>
> 52 posts = 1% (rounded up)
>
> 200 posts = 75%

A reusable version of this formula could look like

```
$progress = round( ( ( $author_posts - $lower ) / ( ( $upper - $lower ) + 1 ) ) * 100 )
```

Where `$upper` and `$lower` boundaries are re-defined within each level.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. In your formula an extra `)` was added that caused an error. :)

Comment: Sorry, I edited without checking. Updated. Please accept if this answered your question.

Comment: Accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if( $author_posts >= '250' ) {
    $progress   = '100';
} elseif( $author_posts < '51' ) {
    $progress   = '0';
} else {
    $progress   = (($author_posts - 50) / 200) * 100;
}

<div class="progress-bar" style="width:<?php echo esc_attr( $progress ); ?>%;"></div>
```